# Google Geocoding API InnerException

Tags: c#, geocoding, google-geocoder, reverse-geocoding

I am using the Google Geocoding API to convert coordinates (latitude and longitude) in an address (Reverse Geocoding),
It was working well for two days and then it stopped working.
The problem is that I have this error message: "There was an error processing the geocoding request. See Status or InnerException for more information."
[EDIT] I tried to catch the InnerException but without success.

```
try
{
    IGeocoder geocoder = new GoogleGeocoder();
    IEnumerable<Address> addresses = geocoder.ReverseGeocode(lon, lat);
    lAddresses = addresses.ToList();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Bad coordinates: " + lon + "/" + lat+'\n'+ex.Message);
}
```

The error is on the geocoder.ReverseGeocode line.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What you get in Inner Exception may help you to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes i tried to catch the InnerException but without success

Comment: @Edoc have you solved this problem?